# Found non-empty schema `schema_name` without metadata table

Tags: java, flyway

I have researched this question and found similar questions but none which have answers that work for me.

Upon trying to run a Spring application, it fails as there is an error starting the ApplicationContext.

This error is a result of a FlywayException

The issue seems to arise as the DB already has a schema named 'schema_name' and flyway doesn't know how to react when it finds this non empty schema. The schema is used by many more packages and classes in the product code with no flyway issues.

The schema already has a flyway_schema_history table which begins with a Flyway Baseline.

The error output is shown below:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema `schema_name` without metadata table! Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the metadata table.
```

I have tried setting flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true but that leads to a further issue in that flyway tries to run the SQL files which originally added the DB tables - which it obviously can't as they exist!

My application.properties file has the following code for DataSource:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema_name
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The pom file contains this for the flyway dependency, where flyway.version is 5.0.7:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

UPDATE

I tried the first answer in which I added fly.baselineOnMigrate and took away the hibernate line but received the following error:

`2019-02-06 10:07:32.233  INFO 82403 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory       : Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema_name (MySQL 5.7)
2019-02-06 10:07:32.272  INFO 82403 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Validated 31 migrations (execution time 00:00.027s)
2019-02-06 10:07:32.318  INFO 82403 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl  : Creating Metadata table: schema_name.schema_version
2019-02-06 10:07:32.379  INFO 82403 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbBaseline     : Schema baselined with version: 1
2019-02-06 10:07:32.395  INFO 82403 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema schema_name: 1
2019-02-06 10:07:32.395  INFO 82403 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema schema_name to version 2.0 - Creates TABLE_NAME tables
2019-02-06 10:07:32.407  WARN 82403 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Table 'TABLE_NAME' already exists (SQL State: 42S01 - Error Code: 1050)
2019-02-06 10:07:32.409 ERROR 82403 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migration of schema schema_name to version 2.0 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to disable this option `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` by setting it's value to `none` or delete it, because it causes Hibernate to update your database schema, but you have a Flyway for that. As it's noted in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional), this property

> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the
>   SessionFactory is created

And the second thing, you have to add this `flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true` property, to make a Flyway working with your not empty schema. Since your Hibernate now will not populate your schema with any data, you won't run into issues with the existing tables.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Stanislav but unfortunately it is not working still.

I'm still getting the migration error as the program still tries to add the existing tables, even having taken out the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` line .

I've edited the original question to show the new error output

Comment: Are you sure, that TABLE_NAME did not exist before you run your app and was not created by some other system? If you are sure, that this table should be created by your app and no one else, then are you running your app on the database, you have never runned before with `hibernate.ddl-auto`? If your app fails, it won't remove table previewsly created by Hibernate

Comment: It seems that the issue was just a flyway version mismatch. I have other packages which were working under very similar settings and the only difference was the flyway version being used! I imagine the newer flyway version picks up the flyway_schema_history table as the metadata table